# why is react component failing test case?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to pass the following test case:

```
it('text should be set to bold when checkbox is checked', () => {
const wrapper = mount(<FontChooser min='2' size='6' max='10' bold='false' 
text='hello' />);
wrapper.find("#boldCheckbox").simulate('change');
expect(wrapper.find('#textSpan').prop('style').fontWeight).to.equal('bold');
});
```

with the following react component:

```
class FontChooser extends React.Component {

   constructor(props) {
   super(props);

   if(this.props.bold=='true'){
      this.state={weight:'bold',checked:true,hidden:true};
   }else {
      this.state={weight:'normal',checked:false,hidden:true};
   }
}

   handleTextClick(){
    this.setState({hidden:!this.state.hidden});

    if(this.props.bold=='true')
        document.getElementById("boldCheckbox").checked = true;
   }

   handleCheckBoxChange(e){
    var checked = e.target.checked;
    this.setState({checked : checked ? true : false ,weight: checked ? 'bold' : 'normal'});
   }

   render() {
     var myWeight=this.state.weight;
     var checked = this.state.checked;

     return(
       <div>
       <input type="checkbox" id="boldCheckbox"
       onChange={this.handleCheckBoxChange.bind(this)} hidden={this.state.hidden} checked={checked} />
       <button id="decreaseButton" hidden={this.state.hidden} >-</button>
       <span id="fontSizeSpan" hidden={this.state.hidden}>{this.props.size}</span>
       <button id="increaseButton" hidden={this.state.hidden}>+</button>
       <span id="textSpan" onClick={this.handleTextClick.bind(this)}
       style={{fontWeight:myWeight}}>{this.props.text} </span>
       </div>
   );
}
}
```

Now here's the really weird part:  If I add

```
this.setState({bold: !this.state.bold});
```

to the end of the handelCheckBoxChange() function and use:

```
var myWeight = (this.state.bold) ? 'bold' : 'normal';
var checked  = (this.state.bold) ? true : false;
```

in the render() function the test passes. Using

```
var myWeight=this.state.weight;
var checked = this.state.checked;
```

console.log() shows the correct values but the test fails.  What the heck is going on?

Answer (score 0):

When you click on your component, `this.setState({hidden:!this.state.hidden})` is called but It will re-render the component later. The re-rendering will append at the end of React update loop aka after `document.getElementById("boldCheckbox").checked = true;` is called.

see [React setState() documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate):

> setState() does not always immediately update the component. It may batch or defer the update until later.

As a result `document.getElementById("boldCheckbox").checked = true;` affects the previous rendering. Not the next one as it should be.

The only way to fix it is either to not call `this.setState()` on click or, as you tried it, manager `bold` value with React state.